# Why threejs pointshadermaterial is rectangular rather than circular when I use a png texture?

Tags: three.js, shader

I have written a points example according to [official example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html), but the result is not happy:

[image]

The point is **Rectangular**, rather than **circular**!

Here is my material code:

```
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: {
                    uColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
                    uPointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(require('./res/spark1')) }
                },
                vertexShader: _me.vertex_shader,
                fragmentShader: _me.fragment_shader,

                transparent: true
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

After some try, like: `blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending`, `fog: false`...I found is related to **depthTest** property, after I set false, result is below:

[image]

see, black square disappeared!Here is final code:

```
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: {
                    uColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
                    uPointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(require('./res/spark1')) }
                },
                vertexShader: _me.vertex_shader,
                fragmentShader: _me.fragment_shader,

                depthTest: false,
                transparent: true
            })
```